# how can i seo angular 4 as frontend and laravel api as backend?

Tags: node.js, angular, laravel

I have a full stack Angular 4 for frontend,  backend is implemented with laravel. Now I wanted to seo server-side rendering Angular, but I do not know how to do this. On the other hand, the language is on the server side is Laravel and I can not use the node.

Is there a way to copy the routes of Laravel exactly and use both laravel and nodejs?

update 1:
when I load a page these error show, but on surface, everything is okay:

> ``` ERROR Response {  _body: '{\n    "message": "",\n    "exception":
>   "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",\n
>   "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",\n
>   "line": 179,\n    "trace": [\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",\n
>   "line": 612,\n            "function": "match",\n            "class":
>   "Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection",\n            "type":
>   "->"\n        },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",\n
>   "line": 601,\n            "function": "findRoute",\n
>   "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",\n            "type":
>   "->"\n        },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",\n
>   "line": 590,\n            "function": "dispatchToRoute",\n
>   "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",\n            "type":
>   "->"\n        },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",\n
>   "line": 176,\n            "function": "dispatch",\n
>   "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",\n            "type":
>   "->"\n        },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",\n
>   "line": 30,\n            "function":
>   "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",\n            "class":
>   "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",\n            "type":
>   "->"\n        },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php",\n
>   "line": 56,\n            "function":
>   "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",\n            "class":
>   "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",\n            "type": "->"\n
>   },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",\n
>   "line": 149,\n            "function": "handle",\n            "class":
>   "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",\n            "type": "->"\n
>   },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",\n
>   "line": 53,\n            "function":
>   "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",\n            "class":
>   "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",\n            "type": "->"\n
>   },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",\n
>   "line": 30,\n            "function":
>   "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",\n            "class":
>   "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",\n            "type": "->"\n
>   },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",\n
>   "line": 149,\n            "function": "handle",\n            "class":
>   "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",\n
>   "type": "->"\n        },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",\n
>   "line": 53,\n            "function":
>   "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",\n            "class":
>   "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",\n            "type": "->"\n
>   },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",\n
>   "line": 30,\n            "function":
>   "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",\n            "class":
>   "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",\n            "type": "->"\n
>   },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",\n
>   "line": 149,\n            "function": "handle",\n            "class":
>   "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",\n
>   "type": "->"\n        },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",\n
>   "line": 53,\n            "function":
>   "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",\n            "class":
>   "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",\n            "type": "->"\n
>   },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",\n
>   "line": 27,\n            "function":
>   "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",\n            "class":
>   "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",\n            "type": "->"\n
>   },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",\n
>   "line": 149,\n            "function": "handle",\n            "class":
>   "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",\n
>   "type": "->"\n        },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",\n
>   "line": 53,\n            "function":
>   "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",\n            "class":
>   "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",\n            "type": "->"\n
>   },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",\n
>   "line": 46,\n            "function":
>   "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",\n            "class":
>   "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",\n            "type": "->"\n
>   },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",\n
>   "line": 149,\n            "function": "handle",\n            "class":
>   "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",\n
>   "type": "->"\n        },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",\n
>   "line": 53,\n            "function":
>   "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",\n            "class":
>   "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",\n            "type": "->"\n
>   },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-cors/src/HandlePreflight.php",\n            "line": 35,\n            "function":
>   "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",\n            "class":
>   "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",\n            "type": "->"\n
>   },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",\n
>   "line": 149,\n            "function": "handle",\n            "class":
>   "Barryvdh\\Cors\\HandlePreflight",\n            "type": "->"\n
>   },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",\n
>   "line": 53,\n            "function":
>   "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",\n            "class":
>   "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",\n            "type": "->"\n
>   },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",\n
>   "line": 102,\n            "function":
>   "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",\n            "class":
>   "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",\n            "type": "->"\n
>   },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",\n
>   "line": 151,\n            "function": "then",\n            "class":
>   "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",\n            "type": "->"\n
>   },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",\n
>   "line": 116,\n            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",\n
>   "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",\n
>   "type": "->"\n        },\n        {\n            "file":
>   "/home/roxo/domains/roxo.ir/public_html/backend/public/index.php",\n
>   "line": 55,\n            "function": "handle",\n            "class":
>   "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",\n            "type":
>   "->"\n        }\n    ]\n}',   status: 404,    ok: false,  statusText:
>   'Not Found',  headers:    Headers {    _headers:    Map {             'server' =>
>   [Array],          'content-type' => [Array],          'transfer-encoding' =>
>   [Array],          'connection' => [Array],            'vary' => [Array],
>             'cache-control' => [Array],             'date' => [Array],
>             'strict-transport-security' => [Array] 
>                     },

```
 _normalizedNames:
      Map {
            'server' => 'server',
            'content-type' => 'content-type',
            'transfer-encoding' => 'transfer-encoding',
            'connection' => 'connection',
            'vary' => 'vary',
            'cache-control' => 'cache-control',
            'date' => 'date',
            'strict-transport-security' => 'strict-transport-security' } 
        },
type: 2,
url: 'https://domainbackend/backend/api/f-product/'
```

}

```
update 2:  this is my server.ts file:

```
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

import 'localstorage-polyfill'
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
// Express Engine
import {ngExpressEngine} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import {provideModuleMap} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

import * as express from 'express';
import {join} from 'path';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');
const template = fs.readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'home', 'index.html')).toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
global['Event'] = null;
global['localStorage'] = localStorage;

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require('./dist/server/main.bundle');

// Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));


app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'home'));

// Example Express Rest API endpoints
// app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'home'), {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

routes:

```
    import { NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {ProgrammingComponent} from "./programming.component";
import {PMainComponent} from "./p-main/p-main.component";
import {ProgrammingChildComponent} from "./programming-child/programming-child.component";
import {ProgrammingPostComponent} from "./programming-post/programming-post.component";


const graphicRoutes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component: ProgrammingComponent,children:[
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'category/all'},
    { path: 'برنامه-نویسی/category', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'category/all'},
    { path: 'category/all', component: PMainComponent},
    {path:'category/:id', component: ProgrammingChildComponent},
    {path:':id', component: ProgrammingPostComponent},
    {path:'search', loadChildren: './main-programming-search/main-programming-search.module#MainProgrammingSearchModule'},
  ]},

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(graphicRoutes)],

  exports: [RouterModule],
})

export class ProgrammingRoutingModule {

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use laravel only as an API and deploy your front-end on nodejs ?

Comment: You really want to use Angular Universal to help SEO.

Comment: @Gilsdav That's exactly what I did, every static content show in view-source but I do not know why any dynamic data do not show on view-source.
I implemented it base on angular universal

Comment: @Barndon I use Angular Universal but every dynamic content not showing in view

Comment: To see how Universal works, you Can take a look at this sample repo: https://github.com/gilsdav/angular-universal-localize-router

Comment: I don't really see what is you need.
Do you have HTML5 redirect error with laravel ?
Or do you want to manage Angular Urls (translations) of Angular App using laravel ? Or still something else ?

Comment: I have only laravel api and send back data to full stack angular web app.

Comment: Do you changed "https://domainbackend/backend/api/f-product/" for this post or is-it in the error ? Do you call same API Url on client and server side ?

Comment: @Gilsdav yes i change it manually, i think the lazy loading modules not working!

Comment: Do you use @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader on your server.ts ?

Comment: I update my question and put server.ts at it

Comment: There are only two ways to achieve SEO with a front end app: 1. server-side rendering, 2. using a static cache in front of the Angular app that robots are redirected to when they hit a certain page. You can achieve #2 with something like prerender.io

Comment: Is it possible to see your routes ? because Universal don't like some syntaxes like {path: '', children: [{path: '', component...}]}

Comment: I added a sample route of programming section that lazy loading

Comment: I think the problem can be your empty path on children. Can you try with flat routes array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is meta tags, lets say the user hits /about

then in your component you add this

about.component.ts:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Meta, Title} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {SettingsService} from '../services/settings.service';
import {ISiteSettings} from '../interfaces/ISiteSettings';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.scss']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
    public site_settings:ISiteSettings;
   constructor( private meta:Meta, private title:Title,private settings_ser:SettingsService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.site_settings.getSettings().subscribe(settings => {
      this.site_settings = settings;
      this.setMeta();
    });
  }

  setNeta(title:string = null,keywords:string = null,description:string = null):void{
    let _t = this.site_settings.title + ' | ' + this.site_settings.description;
    let _k = this.site_settings.keywords;
    let _d = this.site_settings.description;
    if(title && title.length) {
      _t  = title;
    }
    if(keywords && keywords.length){
      _k = keywords;
    }
    if(description && description.length){
      _d = description;
    }
    this.title.setTitle(_t);
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'keywords', content: _k});
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: _d });
  }
}
```

the `settings_ser` makes a call to laravel to get the predefined meta for the about page, once you have it, you update the following meta in the index.html page:

```
<meta name="initial description" content="Boutique Create Agency">
<meta name="initial keywords" content="Boutique Create Agency">
<title>initial title</title>
```

Comment: I used angular Meta and Title  server and set meta description, tags and title. Every static content show fine but any dynamic data do not show

Comment: i used this i didn't have any problem with dynamic data, i guess when you make a call to api and get the data, this is already dynamic right?, cuz you can change the data later from laravel

Comment: yep...maybe the same happening to me and i didn't notice :/

Comment: the only error i see is: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH (css)

Comment: everything fine on this page: 95.211.152.139:4000/profile/roxo
but on each inner product page that error show!

Comment: i think the css error shows when the server says it's going to send data of size x, and then sends data of size y

Comment: I think lazy loading modules in angular not show in view-source

Comment: i figured it out, whenever you have node error that gets logged by Universal, it won't render the page source, in other words, you need to resolve the error that nodes shows you, it's working for me now